# Download / Install Windows Updates from Python

Tags: python, windows, download, installation

I am working on a script to automate the installation of Windows Updates, that I can deploy on several machines so I do not have to worry about updating them manually. I would like to write this in Python, but could not find anythng on how this would be done. I need to know how to search for updates, download the updates and install them all from a python script. Any help would be great!

Comment: is there some reason you don't want to set them up to use Microsoft's automatic updates?

Comment: It really does not make sense to duplicate here Microsoft functionality

Comment: Please consider either marking an answer or adding additional detail to the question. Also, I'd be interested to hear which route you end up going with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start with this: I don't think a Python script is the best tool for the job. If you want to do enterprise-level management of updates (e.g., for all machines on a network), then you should seriously consider using [the existing MS tools](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/enterprise/products/windows-7/management.aspx).

With that said, here is how you might go about this:

1. Have a look at the `windows-update` tag on ServerFault, one of StackOverflow's sister sites: https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-update . A lot of the questions seem to cover command-line control of the update process. Keep in mind that the command line tools vary significantly between e.g. Windows XP on the one hand and Vista/7 on the other. With some luck, you should be able to use windows built-in commands rather than going to the windows update website programmatically.
2. Assuming you find the command-line incantations that you need: Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module to call to the shell and execute those commands programmatically. Because you're using python, you may need to spend quite a bit of time parsing the command outputs to figure out how your shell calls are doing.

Hope that helps. I realize this is a rather high-level answer, but as it stands, the question is not very specific about what exactly you want to accomplish and why you're using python to do it.

Comment: Actually, Python isn't a requirement. I guess I just assumed it would be easier. I was looking in to using VBScript to do this.... any advice there? The reason I would like to write my own script is because I do a LOT of work on different systems, and it would be a LOT easier to just deploy the script, then move on.

Comment: I have no experience with this, but maybe try a PowerShell script: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419 . Again, I don't know if everything you want to do is available from the command-line, but if it is, then at least PSH will help parsing the command outputs (because it receives the output in object form you may have to do less parsing).

Comment: Perhaps worth emphasizing: the existing tools for this are quite fancy... http://www.microsoft.com/windows/enterprise/products/windows-7/management.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Windows update has a [COM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that can be used to scan for and install updates. VBScript is listed as explicitly supported; [python may also be able to access COM interfaces](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html). [Detailed examples in VBscript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be found in Microsoft's documentation.