# How can I make sure the windows update package installed successfully

Tags: python, windows-update

I write a code in python that simulates a Windows Update installation.

the code is below:

```
  subprocess.call(["c:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe","C:/Users/adib/Downloads/WindowsUp.msu", "/quiet")
```

Now, I would like to know when the installation over and make sure the update ran successfully..

how can I do that through the script?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows update has a COM API that can be used to scan for and install updates. VBScript is listed as explicitly supported; python may also be able to access COM interfaces. Detailed examples in VBscript can be found in Microsoft's documentation.

For more information You should take a look at this topic: [Download / Install Windows Updates from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125144/download-install-windows-updates-from-python)